# Is there no way to access the asp.net Response.Headers in IIS6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, http-headers

When I try to access `Request.Headers` I get a "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode." error.

Is there really no way to view the response headers in .net with IIS6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there really is no way to read the headers in IIS6.  You can only add them using `.AddHeader()` or clear them using `.ClearHeaders()`